# How to access method from a computed property in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

In my Vue component I have a single method and a single computed property which calls that method.

Twist is that I have a getter class which stores this getter.

Here is the getter class in a separate .js file:

```js
export default class Getter { constructor(getter) { this.get = getter; } }
```

And here is how I use it in a Vue component:

```js
<script>
    import Getter from "@/model/Getter";
    
    export default
    {
        computed: { property: new Getter(this.getProperty) },

        methods: { getProperty() { alert("getter"); } }
    }
</script>
```

The problem I am getting says that `this` (inside the `Getter` constructor call [line 6]) is `undefined`. I do not know why is that.

If line 6 is replaced with:

```js
computed: { property: new Getter(function() { alert(this); }) },
```

everything works as expected and `this` is defined.

Of course I know that I can define getter inline, and that works, but I am just curious about why my example does not work? Why is in the first example `this` `undefined`?

Getter class is not important here; even without it, it does not work if I do this:

```js
computed: { property: { get: this.getProperty } }
```

Thank you.